# kubernetes connection refused during deployment

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to achieve a zero downtime deployment using kubernetes and during my test the service doesn't load balance well.

My kubernetes manifest is:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
      maxSurge: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
        version: "0.2"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp-container
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-lb
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: myapp
```

If I loop over the service with the external IP, let's say:

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.35.240.1    <none>           443/TCP        1h
myapp-lb     LoadBalancer   10.35.252.91   35.205.100.174   80:30549/TCP   22m
```

using the bash script:

```
while True
    do
        curl 35.205.100.174 
        sleep 0.2s
    done
```

I receive some `connection refused` during the deployment:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.205.100.174 port 80: Connection refused
```

The application is the default [helloapp](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-engine-samples/tree/master/hello-app) provided by Google Cloud Platform and running on `8080`.

Cluster information:

- Kubernetes version: 1.8.8
- Google cloud platform
- Machine type: g1-small

Comment: Is your GCP load balancer a Layer 7 or Layer 4 LB? Because if L7, I would **never** expect connection-refused, no matter what happens to the Pods

Comment: A very interesting experiment would be to run that same while loop but from a Pod *within* the cluster: `while true; do curl 10.35.252.91; sleep 0.2s; done` type deal

Comment: I received a `wget: can't connect to remote host (10.35.252.91): No route to host` in the busybox during a deployment and then it's ok, same issue. For the load balancer, it seems services with `type: LoadBalancer` are Layer 4. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: wow, that's a stumper; are you by chance recreating the `Service` during the deployment, or just doing `kubectl set image deploy myapp-deployment "*=my-new-image"`?

Comment: I'm updating the `version` and doing an apply only on the deployment manifest, still don't get it.

Comment: even with `kubectl set image deployment/myapp-deployment myapp-container=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0`, I still have the `[error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:249: Connection refused` on the service.

Comment: @thoas am facing a very similar issue (using ssl in my case, similar results), were you able to find a solution to your problem? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your request goes to a not started pod. I have avoided this by adding a few parameters:

- `Liveness probe` to be sure app has already started
- `maxUnavalible: 1` to deploy pods one by one

I still have some errors, but they are acceptable because they rarely happen . During the deployment, an error may occur once or twice, so with increasing load you will have a negligible amount of errors. I mean one or two errors per 2000 requests during the deployment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Nick, having some errors during is unacceptable on our side moreover when a simple blue/green with haproxy works like a charm. I still don't understand why it does not work properly and I'm quite surprise since kubernetes should able to deal with this situation quite easy.